# Coloring plot below curve in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

I would like to draw various curves in the same figure, and color the area between the respective curve and a given basevalue.

Here is a toy example of code that I hoped was working, but for some reason the function `area` does not work the way I would expect:

```
x = 0:1/30:30;
y = sin(x);

figure
hold on
for i = 1:3:10
    area(x,y+i,i)
end
```

What I would expect and need is something like this:
[image]

However, what Matlab is plotting is this:
[image]

Is it just too late and I should go to bed or what is the problem here?

Comment: When I copied your code into Matlab it generated a plot similar to the first one.

Comment: @CalvinWhealton I'm getting the same issue. It seems like whenever the `area(x,y+i,i)` command is called after the first one, the `level` of the previous one gets changed to the new one.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what version are you using?

Comment: @CalvinWhealton, ok on my Matlab 2014a it is working the way I expect it. I must check what the other version of Matlab was that I used. I think that it was actually 2014b, but I will go and have a look later!

Answer (score 2):

just use `fill` or `patch` instead of `area` :

```
x = linspace(0,10*pi)
y = sin(x);

figure
hold on
for i = 1:3:10
    patch(x,y+i,i);
end
```

[image]

note that I changed the x limit so y will end on the same value it started with to get the crossed vertical line. For a more generic treatment look [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/7255-areashade).

Comment: Thanks for the solution @bla. But you've already pointed out what makes things more complicated: The traces do not always end on the same value and hence that needs to be taken into account. That's why I wanted to use area, as the function should supply that. Anyway, in 2014a it is working as expected and I have a result now, even though the answer why it was not working is not found, yet. 
Thanks for linking to areashade. It looks promising!